# CRM 2011 How to select the related entity fields in Advanced Find

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am using CRM 2011 Advanced Find on Account Entity to find the Incident CreatedOn Date where Incident is connected to Account.

But when I go to Edit columns it does not give me option to select the Incident CreatedOn Date (Because Advanced find query is on Account Entity). Is there any way to select the Related Entity fields on in search.

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to add the Incident.CreateOn in the Edit Column from the Account entity as you can only add lookup fields (resulted from a N:1 relationship between account and the other entity).

As the Account and Incident have a 1:N relationship, you should be able to add the account column to the Incident columns as stated by Pedro Azevedo. The image below shows you how to do it:

[image: Advanced Find]

Notice that the Record Type will show you a list of the lookup fields you have in the Incident entity and to which entity is relates to - in this case, `Customer` is the relationship name in the Incident entity and `Account` is the related entity.

Cheers, dimamura

Comment: thanks. I can see any email. Could you please attach if you have any.

Comment: I replaced the image with one showing the email fields from the account. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try do this in Incident Entity. You can filter and add columns in both entity.

Comment: Hi, Same thing; can't select the columns from Account connected with Incident.

Comment: Did you change any property of Relationship? Is the only way to hide the the entity. Because in incident entity, press Advanced Find, next in Edit columns, next add columns, next you change the record type to incident. Are you following this steps?